# How can I visualize the size of each group using the facet_wrap option in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

i use geom_bar in ggplot to visualize the purchase decision of customers (3 factor levels purchase, may be, no purchase. The decisions are grouped for several product groups with facet_wrap.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= status_purchase)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ product_group)
```

Not surprisingly this works fine. Do i have any options to visualize another variable for the groups in facet_wrap (e.g. total expenses for each product group)? A kind of bubble in the respective size placed in the right upper corner of the plot or at least the sum of the expenses in the headline would be nice.

Thank you for your answers.

Philipp

Comment: You can add any text to legends/title using paste. Or add arbitrary text to the plot using `geom_text`.

Comment: Quick answer to your question is "yes!", but a more specific answer will depend on what you want to add.  Best option is probably to have a separate dataset that is used to plot labels (if you're looking to put text in each facet), since it looks like you're wanting some summary data shown, right?  Can you specify a bit more what you would want specifically and provide an example of what you want to show?

Answer (score 0):

OP.  In the absence of a specific example, let me demonstrate one way to do this that uses `geom_text()` to display summary data for a given dataset that is separated in to facets.

In this example, I'll use the `txhousing` dataset (which is part of `ggplot2`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- txhousing
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=month, y=sales)) + geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~year)
```

[image]

Let's say we wanted to display a red total of sales for a year in the upper right portion of each facet.  The easiest way to do this is to first calculate our summary data in a separate dataset, then overlay that information according to the facets via `geom_text()`.

```
df_summary <- df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(sales, na.rm = TRUE))

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=month, y=sales)) + geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~year) +
  geom_text(
    data=df_summary, x=12, y=33000, aes(label=total),
    hjust=1, color='red', size=3
  )
```

[image]

I override the mapping for the `x` and `y` aesthetics in the `geom_text()` call.  As long as the `df_summary` dataset contains a column called `year`, the data will be placed on the facets properly.

I hope you can apply a similar idea to your particular question.

Comment: Thank you this solution works fine. I used geom_label instead.